# Is it possible to allow one std::function type accept lambdas with different signatures

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I have a higher order function `map` which is similar to STL `for_each`, and maps a `std::function` object over a `vector` of things.

```
template<class T, class U>
vector<U> map(function<U (T)> f, vector<T> xs) {
  vector<U> ret;
  for (auto &x: xs)
    ret.push_back(f(x));
  return ret;
}
```

Now, I want to have this higher order function take both objects of types `function<int (const vector<T>&)>` and  `function<int (vector<T>)>`, as shown in the attached minimal example.

The problem is that `function<int (const vector<T>&)>` and  `function<int (vector<T>)>` seem to be convertible to each other (see `head` and `head2`), but `map` won't take the const references version `function<int (const vector<int>&)>` (see `Q1`).

It is possible to tell `map` to accept the const reference version with explicit conversion (`Q2`), but this is rather cumbersome.

I was wondering if, in general, it is possible to write a function `deref` that removes the const reference from `function<int (const vector<T>&)>` and returns a `function<int (vector<T>)>`?

(If above is possible, then I won't have to write two identical overloads/implementations of map for const refs).

Thanks.

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<class T, class U>
vector<U> map(function<U (T)> f, vector<T> xs) {
  vector<U> ret;
  for (auto &x: xs)
    ret.push_back(f(x));
  return ret;
}

int main() {
  vector<vector<int>> m;
  function<int (const vector<int>&)> head  =  [](const vector<int>& a) {return a[0];};
  function<int (const vector<int>&)> head1 =  [](vector<int> a) {return a[0];}; //conversion OK
  function<int (vector<int>)> head2 =  [](const vector<int>& a) {return a[0];}; //conversion OK
  map(head2,m); //OK

  map(head,m); //Q1: problem line, implicit conversion NOT OK
  map(function<int (vector<int>)>(head),m); //Q2: explicit conversion OK
  map(deref(head),m); //Q3: ??How-to, deref takes a std::function f and returns a function with const ref removed from its signature

  return 0;
}
```

--- EDIT ---

I am particularly interested in a `deref` like function or a meta-function that can remove the const ref from the type signature of a `std::function` object, so that I can at least do `Q2` automatically.

I know that, as @Brian and @Manu correctly pointed out, the use of `std::function` to specify types is not conventional, but I wonder what I asked above is even feasible. *Personally*, I think code with `std::function` has greater clarity, considering how generic function types `Func<T1, T2, T3, ...,Tn, Tresult>` are used in C#. This is if the cost of type erasure is tolerable.

I fully agree that c++ can infer return types and give an error message when type is wrong. Maybe it's just a matter of taste and I would prefer to spell it out when writing function signatures.

Comment: Don't use `std::function` as `map` function parameter. Use just a template. That reduces the coupling you are experimenting and also improves performance allowing the compiler to do inlining.

Answer (score 21):

I understand why you are using `std::function`: You have to know the return type of the transformation to create the vector, right?

But consider a completely different approach. Given the metafunction `std::result_of` you could compute the result type of a function call, so just write:

```
template<typename F , typename CONTAINER , typename T = typename std::result_of<F(typename CONTAINER::value_type)>::type>
std::vector<T> map( F f , CONTAINER&& container )
{
    std::vector<T> result;

    for( auto& e : container )
        result.emplace_back( f( e ) );

    return result;
}
```

#### Advantages:

- **No abuse of `std::function`**: Always think what `std::function` does (i.e. type erasure), don't use it as an universal function type.
- **Rely on duck typing instead of coupling on the types**: Don't worry, if something was wrong it wouldn't compile neither.
- **Works for any Standard Library Container** since we extracted the element type with the `value_type` trait, instead of using `std::vector` directly.
- **The code is much more clear and efficient**, both because the reduction of `std::function` usage.

#### Regarding the question "*Its possible to write a function that accepts lambdas of multiple signatures?*"

Using `std::function` you could write something similar to Boost.OverloadedFunction in a couple of lines:

```
template<typename F , typename... Fs>
struct overloaded_function : public std_function<F> , public std_function<Fs>...
{
    overloaded_function( F&& f , Fs&&... fs ) :
        std_function<F>{ f },
        std_function<Fs>{ fs }...
    {}
};
```

Where `std_function` is a metafunction which given a function type `F` returns the `std::function` instance with the signature of `F`. I leave it as a game/challenge for the reader.

Thats all. Improve it with a make-like function:

```
template<typename F , typename... Fs>
overloaded_function<F,Fs...> make_overloaded_function( F&& f , Fs&&... fs )
{
    return { std::forward<F>( f ) , std::forward<Fs>( fs )... };
}
```

And you are ready to go:

```
auto f = make_overloaded_function( [](){ return 1; } ,
                                   [](int,int){ return 2; } ,
                                   [](const char*){ return 3; } );

f();        //Returns 1
f(1,2);     //Returns 2
f("hello"); //Returns 3
```

#### EDIT: "*Thanks. But, what I am really looking for, is a meta-function that takes the signature of a callable, and removes the const refs from the signature.*"

Ok, let me try: The `std::decay` metafunction applies the decaying done when passing argumments by value to a given type. This includes removing cv qualifiers, removing references, etc. So a metafunction like yours could be something that takes a function signature type and applies decaying to all its argumments:

```
template<typename F>
struct function_decay;

template<typename R typename... ARGS>
struct function_decay<R(ARGS...)>
{
    using type = R(typename std::decay<ARGS>::type...);
};
```

That should do the work.

*I have written this because you explicitly asked for it in the comment, but I strongly encourage you to use the alternative I showed you initially, because it has many advantages compared to your way.

That said, I hope this answer helped to solve your problem.*

Comment: Note he sometimes wants mutable inputs, so I would change `const CONTAINER&` into `CONTAINER&&`.  Also take `F` as `F&&`, not for forwarding, but as a perfect reference.

Comment: @Manu343726 Thanks. But, what I am really looking for, is a meta-function that takes the signature of a callable, and removes the const refs from the signature. That's the 'deref' part in the OP.

Comment: @Manu343726 Thanks for the advice, I will keep that in mind. I will try to use your `function_decay` meta_function, and figure out the `std_function` part of the exercise.

Comment: @Manu343726 Could you, please, post, how `std_function` should look like?

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic solution is to simply allow `map` to take an arbitrary function-like type,

```
template<class T, class F>
auto map(F f, vector<T> xs) -> vector<typename result_of<F(T)>::type> {
  vector<typename result_of<F(T)>::type> ret;
  for (auto &x: xs)
    ret.push_back(f(x));
  return ret;
}
```

The main issue with this approach is that you get confusing error messages if `F` is not callable with arguments of type `T`, or if it returns something strange, like `void`.

(A secondary issue is that the first argument to `map` can't be an overloaded function; the compiler won't simply be able to pick the overload that takes an argument of type `T`.)

(You might also want to consider decaying the return type of `f`.)

Comment: +1 Five seconds before me, Nooooooo, you beat me ;).